# Character moving code not working- Unity3D unityscript

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, unityscript

I have a script that moves the character in directions depends on what it collides with. Heres my code:

```
var speed : float = 1;
private var leftBool : boolean;
private var rightBool : boolean;
private var upBool : boolean;
private var downBool : boolean;

function Update () {
    if(leftBool == true) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.x =         gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.x - speed * Time.deltaTime;
        rightBool = false;
        upBool = false;
        downBool = false;
    }
    if(upBool == true) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y = gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y + speed * Time.deltaTime;
        rightBool = false;
        leftBool = false;
        downBool = false;
    }
    if(rightBool == true) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.x = gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.x + speed * Time.deltaTime;
        rightBool = false;
        leftBool = false;
        downBool = false;
    }
    if(downBool == true) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y = gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y - speed * Time.deltaTime;
        rightBool = false;
        leftBool = false;
        upBool = false;
    }   
}

function Start () {
    leftBool = true;
}


function OnTriggerEnter2D (other : Collider2D) {
    if(other.GetComponent(Arrows).rotationNumber == 1) {
        leftBool = true;
        Debug.Log("Entered");
    }
    if(other.GetComponent(Arrows).rotationNumber == 2) {
        upBool = true;
        Debug.Log("Entered");
    }
    if(other.GetComponent(Arrows).rotationNumber == 3) {
        rightBool = true;
        Debug.Log("Entered");
    }
    if(other.GetComponent(Arrows).rotationNumber == 4) {
        downBool = true;
        Debug.Log("Entered");
    }
}
```

It shows "Entered" in the debug.log but the character doesn't change directions when it collides. Why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: Imtaj left a great answer, but there are other issues with your code. (1) Instead of writing of `something == true` you should always write just `something`, because it's essentially the same thing. (2) GetComponent operation can be costly, especially in non-generic form, so you should probably cache the rigidbody if you're doing it every frame. (3) The logic that you have here is essentially a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) and it would be a good idea to express it like that in code, which would actually help you prevent this bug.

Answer (score 1):

At first when colliding suppose with rotationNumber==1, leftBool remains true. Others are false as per your code in declaration and Update(). Now, when you collide with rotationNumber==2, upBool returns true. But as earlier, leftBool is still true in Update(), and it is on the top of the code execution order, upBool will return to false immediately. So, you will never get if(upBool == true){} things (By the way, you don't have to use == operator for bools, if(upBool) for true and if(!upBool) for false). Hope it will clear up your confusion. Now, there are lot of ways to achieve what you want. But, here is something I modified your codes so that you may understand what's going on -

```
var speed : float = 1;
private var leftBool : boolean;
private var rightBool : boolean;
private var upBool : boolean;
private var downBool : boolean;

function Start () {
    leftBool = true;
}

function Update () {
    if(leftBool) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.x = gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.x - speed * Time.deltaTime; 
    }
    if(upBool) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y = gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y + speed * Time.deltaTime;   
    }
    if(rightBool) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.x = gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.x + speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if(downBool) {
        gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y = gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y - speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }   
}

function OnTriggerEnter2D (other : Collider2D) {
    if(other.GetComponent(Arrows).rotationNumber == 1) {
        leftBool = true;
        rightBool = false;
        upBool = false;
        downBool = false;
        Debug.Log("Entered");
    }
    if(other.GetComponent(Arrows).rotationNumber == 2) {
        upBool = true;
        rightBool = false;
        leftBool = false;
        downBool = false;
        Debug.Log("Entered");
    }
    if(other.GetComponent(Arrows).rotationNumber == 3) {
        rightBool = true;
        upBool = false;
        leftBool = false;
        downBool = false;
        Debug.Log("Entered");
    }
    if(other.GetComponent(Arrows).rotationNumber == 4) {
        downBool = true;
        rightBool = false;
        leftBool = false;
        upBool = false;
        Debug.Log("Entered");
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: It sort of worked. It changed the direction but slightly. When it changes the direction from left to up it would go diagonally. I want it to stop moving left and move up straight away. If it doesn't work with rigidbody, is there another way to move the character? Thanks

Comment: If your game isn't truly physics based, you can try transform.position or transform.Translate etc.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use tranform.translate? I have tried it before but it never worked. (My game is a 2d game) Thanks.